# PHP, add a newline with implode

Tags: php, implode

I'm trying to add a newline `\n`, in my foreach statement with implode.

My code:

```
$ga->requestReportData($profileId,array('country'),array('visits')); 
$array = array();
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){ 
    $array[] = "['".$result->getcountry()."', ".$result->getVisits()."]"; 
} 
echo implode(",\n", $array);
```

I only get a comma and a space between my results.  I want a comma and a newline.

I am trying to get something like this:

> ['Country', 'number'],
>
> ['Country', 'number'],
>
> ['Country', 'number']

However I I get this:

> ['Country', 'number'], ['Country', 'number'], ['Country', 'number']

Why does my \n not cause a newline?

Comment: Can you show your array and the result you are trying to get?

Comment: make sure you are printing your result in a `<pre></pre>` tag or you will only see a space

Comment: try `implode( ",\n",$array); ` see: http://bd1.php.net/function.implode

Comment: Not working in this way ...

Comment: well, first of all, post your real code. second: explain what's the problem. "not working" is ridiculously vague. (and check the answers...)

Comment: You shouldn't be manually generating json strings.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suspect it is because you are echoing the data to the browser and it's not showing the line break as you expect. If you wrap your implode in the the `<pre>` tags, you can see it is working properly.

Additionally, your arguments are backwards on your [implode](https://www.php.net/function.implode) function, according to current documentation. However, for historical reasons, parameters can be in either order.

```
$array = array('this','is','an','array');
echo "<pre>".implode(",\n",$array)."</pre>";
```

Output:

```
this,
is,
an,
array
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs: `implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.`

Comment: Is there any option without `<pre>` tag

Answer (score 28):

For cross-platform-compatibility use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n`.

Using the example from the accepted answer above:

```
$array = array('this','is','another','way');
echo "<pre>".implode(PHP_EOL, $array)."</pre>";
```

If you're writing directly to HTML (it wouldn't work on files) there is an option of using `<br>` like this:

```
$array = array('this','is','another','way');
echo "<p>".implode(<br>, $array)."</p>";
```

Both output:

```
this, 
is, 
another, 
way
```

Comment: Correct answer. It also addressed the portability issues.

Comment: Using PHP_EOL worked for me when adding to a text area input

Comment: PHP_EOL worked (In laravel). If you want ',' also,  then you can write this way:  implode(','.PHP_EOL, $array).

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, '\n' will not work on windows and if you accidantally write '\n' instead of "\n", it won't work too.

Answer (score 4):

This can also work

```
$array = array('one','two','three','four');
echo implode("<br>", $array);
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score -1):

Many others claim you use the wrong order, that's only partial right, because the docs only recommend this, but you don't have to:

> implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either
>   order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less
>   confusing to use the documented order of arguments.

I think your problem is caused by how browsers interpret HTML. They don't care about newlines, they're like a normal space for them.

To show these linebreaks, you can use `<pre><?php echo implode($glue, $array); ?></pre>`. You could also use `nl2br(implode(..))` or `nl2br(implode(..), true)` if you're writing XHTML.