# Laravel implode array items to new lines

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my array from `hasMany` relationship in Laravel framework.

```
$array = ['php','css','hrml'];
```

How can I display as below using implode function. (code in my view is `{{ $photo->tags->pluck('tag')->implode(",\n") }}`)

Expected out put:

php,

css,

html

**Should be on the next line**

Comment: It's a duplicate question please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584164/php-add-a-newline-with-implode

Comment: @MayankDudakiya saw this already not woking for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Displaying Unescaped Data**

You can use `<br>` in the implode function and By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax `{!! !!}`:

```
{!! $photo->tags->pluck('tag')->implode(",<br>") !!}
```

**Output:**

php,
css,
html

Comment: `Desert,<br />Nature,<br />Natural environment,<br />Sand,<br />Sky,<br />Natural landscape,<br />death valley landscape` - not working

Comment: @Bira instead of `{{ }}` use `{!! !!}`

Comment: Please explain your answer, it will be helpful to others.

Comment: Does this solution not bring a security risk? I would like to display the <br> as html, without enabling the posibility for html in the variable to be executed.

Comment: @RobinBastiaan This is not a security risk. Because we use this `{!! !!}` for rendering the html and this is the functionality of Laravel blade.

Comment: @InzamamIdrees When rendering a variable with `{!! !!}` it is not escaped and thus is a potential security risk when the variable contains user supplied data. Any (malicious) html from the user will then be executed.

Comment: @RobinBastiaan then this is the exceptional case, for this we handle the exceptions from controller maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this,

```
$tag = ['php','css','hrml'];

echo implode("<br />" ,$tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

The more secure way to handle this in Blade:

```
@foreach ($photo->tags->pluck('tag') as $tag)
    {{ $tag }} {{ $loop->last ? '' : '<br>' }}
@endforeach
```

Yes, this is not a single line solution, but it does make your application more secure.

When rendering a variable with `{!! $variable !!}` it is not escaped and thus is a potential security risk when the variable contains user supplied data. Any (malicious) html from the user would then be executed. It is better to resolve this the secure way by default. Only use the `{!! $variable !!}` syntax when you are sure that the data in the variable is safe to be displayed.